# Spring Boot application not starting up

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have cloned a repo from github:

https://github.com/Blacktoviche/springboot-graphql-sqqr-jwt-demo

I am trying to follow the instructions, but when I try doing `mvn install` - i get errors - one and only test fails (the default `contextLoads()` test)

When I run `mvn spring-boot:run`, it fails producing an error:

```
[INFO ] 2019-09-09 13:56:14.628 [main] SpringbootGraphqlSqqrJwtDemoApplication - Starting SpringbootGraphqlSqqrJwtDemoApplication on choroszcz with PID 2701 (/home/znitecki/IdeaProjects/springboot-graphql-sqqr-jwt-demo/target/classes started by znitecki in /home/znitecki/IdeaProjects/springboot-graphql-sqqr-jwt-demo)
[INFO ] 2019-09-09 13:56:14.635 [main] SpringbootGraphqlSqqrJwtDemoApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[INFO ] 2019-09-09 13:56:16.208 [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1524 ms
[ERROR] 2019-09-09 13:56:17.247 [main] SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.prime.graphql.SpringbootGraphqlSqqrJwtDemoApplication.main(SpringbootGraphqlSqqrJwtDemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
```

I really need this app to get working, I have no idea why is it failing.

What can I do to make it work? What additional info can I provide?

Comment: You stacktrace is incomplete.

Comment: This may occur for multiple reasons. post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden i've provided a fuller stacktracer

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam i am working on Java 12 - OpenJDK

Answer (score 3):

From the stack trace I can see you are using Spring 5.0.6 which is not supported on Java 12. You have to use Spring 5.1.x. Also Spring Boot 2.1 is the version supported on Java 11.

So you have the following options.

1. Use Java 8 without upgrading Spring Boot.
2. Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1 and use Java 11.
3. Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1.7 or above and use Java 12.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.1.7 (and later) supports Java 12. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements.